# what is the correct path of Access database when deployment an application

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, deployment

I did an application in c# language using visual studio 2010.
I used this connection statements to connect to an Access database:

```
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
        Source=..\\Data\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";    

        connect.Open();
        command = new OleDbCommand();

        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = "Sql query";
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        connect.Close()
```

when I deployed the application and then execute I got some errors ( database not found, the path of the database not correct).

My question is what is the correct path that should I used to reach the database after deployment the application?

Answer (score 0):

The correct path is the path from the location where the EXE is running, or where the web app is running to the database (the path you have shown is a relative path - the double-dot-double-slash means 'go up one folder from where you are running'.